# Trouble printing a variable

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and coding in general, sorry if this question seems elementary to most of you. I'm trying to write a little program where a code is generated, and basically you have infinte guesses to guess the correct code. Once I get that down I plan to do it number by number, so you just guess the first number until you get that correct, and then the second number, and so on... Right now I'm just playing around with what I have written so far and I'm just trying to get the code to display right in the start but its not working out because it says **"object has no attribute 'code'."** and I was hoping someone could point out my mistake.

**Tracker.py**

```
from Number import *

class Runner(object):
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start
        print Integer.__doc__
        print Integer.code

    def play(self):
        next_guess = self.start

Integer = Random_Integer()

Guess = Runner(Integer)

Guess.play()
```

**Number.py**

```
from random import randint

class Random_Integer(object):
"""Welcome to the guessing game! You have unlimited attempts
to guess the 3 random numbers, thats pretty much it.
"""
    def __init__(self):
        code = "%d%d%d" % (randint(1,9), randint(1,9), randint(1,9))
```

Comment: `Integer.__init__.code` !!!!!

Comment: Is the indentation displayed your actual indentation?

Comment: No the indentation is coming out weird, it's formatted correctly in the display screen on 'edit' but its showing up weird here, not sure why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to print the attribute `code` of the `Integer.__init__` method. That attribute does not exist.

Local variables of a function are not exposed; you cannot reach `code` unless you make it a *instance* attribute:

```
class Random_Integer(object):
    """Welcome to the guessing game! You have unlimited attempts
    to guess the 3 random numbers, thats pretty much it.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.code = "%d%d%d" % (randint(1,9), randint(1,9), randint(1,9))
```

then

```
class Runner(object):
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start
        print start.__doc__
        print start.code
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make `code` an instance variable of the Random_Integer class, you need to use `self.code` in `__init__()`